# excel sheets data copy and paste while column header count differs

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007, spreadsheet

How to paste records from one excel sheet to another while column header count differs between 2 sheets.

**Example**

```
Sheet1 -> S.No, Name, Age, DOB, etc... up to 150 columns..

Sheet2 -> Name, DOB, Gender, etc.. up to 50 columns..
```

My aim is to copy all the fields records of sheet2 from sheet1 and paste it into sheet2. Is there any efficient way for this to achieve. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use formula `=INDEX(Sheet8!$A2:$E2;MATCH(A$1;Sheet8!$A$1:$E$1;0))` in first cell and copy to all ranges, like this image :
[image]